# HTTP 400 Bad Request

Tags: c++, sockets, http

I am trying a bit of socket programming in C++. I manage to connect to the Host-Server fine, but receive a 400 Bad Request Error. I reckon that I somehow botch the HTTP message. This is the message in question (using \n for line breaks):

```
POST CMD=Put&PROGRAM=blastp&DATABASE=swissprot&QUERY=KPFPAPQTPGRLQAL http/1.1
HOST: ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

For some reason things work alright when I use a Perl script or just enter the corresponding URL into a browser.

The working snippets of Perl code are:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use URI::Escape;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$args = "CMD=Put&PROGRAM=blastp&DATABASE=swissprot&QUERY=KPFPAPQTPGRLQAL";
$req = new HTTP::Request POST => 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi';
$req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$req->content($args);
$response = $ua->request($req);
print $response->content;
exit 0;
```

The corresponding URL is:

```
http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?CMD=Put&PROGRAM=blastp&DATABASE=swissprot&QUERY=KPFPAPQTPGRLQAL
```

What did I do wrong? Please, find the complete C++ code below.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int s, error;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

if((s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
{
    cout<<"Error 01: creating socket failed!\n";
    close(s);
    return 1;
}

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(80);
inet_aton("204.27.61.92",&addr.sin_addr);

error = connect(s,(sockaddr*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
if(error!=0)
{
    cout<<"Error 02: conecting to server failed!\n";
    close(s);
    return 1;
}

char msg[] = "POST CMD=Put&PROGRAM=blastp&DATABASE=swissprot&QUERY=KPFPAPQTPGRLQAL http/1.1\nHOST: ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/Blast.cgi\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n\n";

char answ[1024];

send(s,msg,sizeof(msg),0);

ssize_t len;
while((len = recv(s, answ, 1024, 0)) > 0)
    {
       cout.write(answ, len);    
    }

if(len < 0)
{
}    

close(s);    

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Line endings in `HTTP` should be `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the data you are sending it doesn't look like a valid `POST` request. Your line endings are wrong, they should be `"\r\n"` and the message order of your data appears to be the wrong way round.

You might try something like this: (untested)

```
    std::string post_data = "CMD=Put&PROGRAM=blastp&DATABASE=swissprot&QUERY=KPFPAPQTPGRLQAL";

    std::string msg;

    msg += "POST /blast/Blast.cgi http/1.1\r\n";
    msg += "Host: ncbi.nlm.nih.gov\r\n";
    msg += "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    msg += "Content-Length: " + std::to_string(post_data.size()) + "\r\n";
    msg += "\r\n";
    msg += post_data;

    int len = send(s, msg.data(), msg.size(), 0);

    if(len == -1)
        throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! You cleaned up my message nicely.